# Make a black background transparent in the compositor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

[image]I'm having trouble adding a render layer, the layers I have are:

- Stars
- Sky
- Clouds
- Billboard (problem)

I've managed to merge together stars, sky and clouds. However I'm having trouble adding the billboard layer. The rest show through one another but the billboard layer has a black background.

How can I make just that layer transparent?

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!
You might in the future add more details to your questions, so it will be easier to identify the issue and solution. I hope I understood corretly.

Comment: Was the billboard generated in blender? If so, just set the background to be transparent instead of black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First Possibility

You might use the *Color / Mix / Add* node, or use the *Color / Mix / Mix* and with *Fac* of your billboards luminosity, which can be obtained with the *Converter / Separate HSVA* node.

[image: Mix with Luminosity]

## Second Possibility

Insert a *Converter / Math / Bigger Than* node between the *Separate HSVA* and the *Mix* nodes abowe. This will only make totally black pixels transparent.

## Third Solution

If your Billboard is rendered in Blender, you can set the background of the render to be transparent. In *Blender Internal* renderer set *Properties Panel / Render / Shading / Alpha* to Transparent. In *Cycles* renderer set the *Properties Panel / Render / Film / Transparent* checkbox to true.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its sort of done what I wanted it do to, however its made the model transparent as well (I've added a screen shot to my original post as that most likely would have been helpful the first time lol).

Comment: I have updated my answere.

Comment: Thank you, seriously!!! your second solution worked perfectly. Man I was so stressed about that.